# Shortest path in paragliding race

Tags: algorithm, optimization, coordinates, shortest-path

I'm a paragliding pilot. A paragliding race is defined as a set of virtual buoys. The pilot who flies through all buoys first wins.

A buoy is defined with two parameters:

- the coordinates of a point
- a radius

This defines a cylinder in a 3D space, but for simplicity let's keep the problem in 2D. A race could look something like this (approximate drawing):
[image: race]
A=1000m; B=3000m; C=2000m; D=500m

The pilot should start inside circle A, then fly inside circle B and C (or at least just 'touch' it) and should end inside circle D.

**How do you calculate the optimal (shortest) path?**

The result should be the coordinates of all segments that make part of the shortest path.

Comment: You can use a constrained gradient descent, or some of the second order quasi-newton alternatives.

Comment: Question, does the pilot have to go in a particular order?  That is, in your diagram can you go from A  to C to D to B if that is shorter?

Comment: Also not a solution, but an observation.  The shortest path will, if extended, start at A and end at E, and be a path that light could take if each circle was either perfectly reflective (turn around at that point) or transparent (pass through a circle towards the next one).

Comment: Do you really want the shortest path? This will not be physically realizable as its tangents are discontinuous.

Comment: Shortest path is not necessarily the fastest. A wind direction is very important.

Comment: @btilly yes, the order should be followed, can not skip or reorder

Comment: @btilly, nice though experiment with the light. I was trying to approach it from a geometric point of view.

Comment: @NicoSchertler yes, the sortest path. And it is realizable

Comment: @user58697 there are also a lot of variables that influence the fastest route, but this is a different problem. This is how to get the shortest path.

Comment: @btilly how do you prove something like that?

Comment: @MaximilianoPadulo where is this question from?

Comment: @Yonlif Through proof by contradiction.  Any path that doesn't fit that description can trivially be improved on by moving a segment or two towards meeting that description.  And therefore the best must meet that description.

Comment: @btilly Yes I understood, trying to figure out if I can make this problem easier by expanding the solution for only 3 circles.

Comment: @Yonlif from nowhere. It's a problem i'm currently having and want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If the path is known *a priori* to be ABCD and only the exact points are unknown, then the total distance (squared) can be written as a function of 4 variables.

One parameterization of point i is of course

```
x(t_i) = x0_i + r_i * cos(t_i)
y(t_i) = y0_i + r_i * sin(t_i)
```

The path length squared is

```
D^2 = sum_{i = 1, n-1} (x(t_{i+i}) - x(t_i))^2 + (y(t_{i+i}) - y(t_i))^2
```

The four variables you're solving for are t_1,...t_4. After substitution, the final expression for D^2 is a pretty hairy quadratic over sine and cosine. You're out to minimize that quantity.

This is not something likely to admit an analytic solution.

You could also try a rational quadratic parameterization of the circle, but you'd end up with a rational quartic. Not much (any?) simpler.

Happily even such hairy functions can be minimized by standard numerical non-linear optimization algorithms such as (as someone suggested in comments) gradient descent.

In the general case, you can't guarantee that minimums found by such algorithms  are global. But here it seems the solution space might be convex, at least for most problem instances, which makes a local minimum also global.

There's also likely to exist good heuristic ways of choosing starting points for the numerical iteration. For example take the path along the *centers* of the circles. For each circle pick the midpoint between its two intersections with the path.

With similar logic you can constrain the values of each t_i to a range always less than \pi.